# Do we have $\epsilon(h)=\epsilon(h_{(1)})\epsilon(h_{(2)})$?

Tags: hopf-algebras

Let $H$ be a Hopf algebra and $\epsilon: H \to \mathbb{C}$ the counit. Do we have $\epsilon(h)=\epsilon(h_{(1)})\epsilon(h_{(2)})$?

I think that $h = \epsilon(h_{(1)})h_{(2)}$. Therefore $\epsilon(h) = \epsilon(\epsilon(h_{(1)})h_{(2)}) = \epsilon(h_{(1)})\epsilon(h_{(2)})$. Is this correct? Here $h_{(1)}\otimes h_{(2)} = \Delta(h)$. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument is correct: $$\epsilon(h) = \epsilon(\epsilon(h_{(1)})h_{(2)}) = \epsilon(h_{(1)})\epsilon(h_{(2)})$$
due to the facts that:

- the compatibility condition between the comultiplication and the counity is:
  $$
  (Id\otimes\epsilon)\circ\Delta=(\epsilon\otimes Id)\circ\Delta=
  Id \Leftrightarrow \\
  \Leftrightarrow 
  h_{(1)}\epsilon(h_{(2)}))=\epsilon(h_{(1)})h_{(2)}=h
  $$
- and the counity map $\epsilon: H \to \mathbb{C}$, is by definition, $\mathbb{C}$-linear.